# pandas groupby rolling behaviour

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Here my pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'location': ['USA','USA','USA','USA', 'France','France','France','France'],
'date':['2020-11-20','2020-11-21','2020-11-22','2020-11-23', '2020-11-20','2020-11-21','2020-11-22','2020-11-23'],
'dm':[5.,4.,2.,2.,17.,3.,3.,7.]
})
```

For a precise location (so groupby is needed) I want the mean of dm over 2 days. If I use this :

```
df['rolling']=df.groupby('location').dm.rolling(2).mean().values
```

I obtain this incorrect pandas

```
    location    date    dm  rolling
0   USA     2020-11-20  5.0     NaN
1   USA     2020-11-21  4.0     10.0
2   USA     2020-11-22  2.0     3.0
3   USA     2020-11-23  2.0     5.0
4   France  2020-11-20  17.0    NaN
5   France  2020-11-21  3.0     4.5
6   France  2020-11-22  3.0     3.0
7   France  2020-11-23  7.0     2.0
```

While it should be:

```
    location    date    dm  rolling
0   USA     2020-11-20  5.0     NaN
1   USA     2020-11-21  4.0     4.5
2   USA     2020-11-22  2.0     3.0
3   USA     2020-11-23  2.0     2.0
4   France  2020-11-20  17.0    NaN
5   France  2020-11-21  3.0     10
6   France  2020-11-22  3.0     3.0
7   France  2020-11-23  7.0     5.0
```

Two questions:

- what my syntax is actually doing ?
- what is the correct way to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is problem `groupby` create new level of `MultiIndex`, so for matching original index values is necessary remove it by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`, if use `.value` then is no alignemnt by index, so order should be different like here:

```
df['rolling']=df.groupby('location').dm.rolling(2).mean().reset_index(level=0, drop=True) 
print (df)
  location        date    dm  rolling
0      USA  2020-11-20   5.0      NaN
1      USA  2020-11-21   4.0      4.5
2      USA  2020-11-22   2.0      3.0
3      USA  2020-11-23   2.0      2.0
4   France  2020-11-20  17.0      NaN
5   France  2020-11-21   3.0     10.0
6   France  2020-11-22   3.0      3.0
7   France  2020-11-23   7.0      5.0
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.groupby('location').dm.rolling(2).mean())
location   
France    4     NaN
          5    10.0
          6     3.0
          7     5.0
USA       0     NaN
          1     4.5
          2     3.0
          3     2.0
Name: dm, dtype: float64

print (df.groupby('location').dm.rolling(2).mean().reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
4     NaN
5    10.0
6     3.0
7     5.0
0     NaN
1     4.5
2     3.0
3     2.0
Name: dm, dtype: float64
```